# Area 51 reminder system sends mail when it shouldn't

Tags: bug, area-51, email

I just got an annoyotron mail asking why I wasn't active on Woodworking. I am active on woodworking.

Can this be fixed?

Answer (score 2):

Looks like your [Area 51 account](http://area51.stackexchange.com/users/121845?tab=accounts) is not associated with your account on https://woodworking.stackexchange.com and that's why you got the email. (it's listed properly in your [network profile](https://stackexchange.com/users/3768354/keshlam?tab=accounts))

You probably used different email for Area 51, to fix this click "my logins" in the info tab of your profile page in Area 51 and add the OpenID you're using elsewhere on Stack Exchange in there.

Comment: Suspected some such disconnect but wasn't sure where to look; thanks!

Comment: Cheers, keep us updated if this really solves the issue i.e. not getting such emails again in few days. :)